# Java applet failing to run. Usually solutions not working

Tags: java, applet

I am just getting started trying to run a very simple applet in a web page and for some reason I can not get any result.

Things I currently know:

- Running on Windows 8.1.  Attempted to use both Chrome (preferred) and IE.
- I do have Java enabled in my browser settings.
- The applet does run when executed in Eclipse (Luna).  It is nothing more than a simple "Hello World" type applet.
- I am not using the "applet" tag in my HTML.  I am using the "object" tag.  I am using the simplest settings for the tag.
- I am using the latest version of Java.
- I have tried turning off Ad blockers.
- My security settings are set to allow me to run this one webpage locally for my testing purposes (ie it is on the "allowed" list).

I am getting no error messages of any kind, I am simply not seeing my applet in the web page.

I have looked around here and other sources and all the solutions I have found have been something related to the above but none seem to be working for me at this time.

Thoughts?

Comment: You should display the java console.  I believe it is in the advanced java settings.

Comment: Why are you trying to use applets? It is outdated technology now, use html5 and bunch of JavaScript.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I am expirementing and need to get through this first.  Thanks.

Comment: *"but I am expirementing"*  With what, specifically?  What are you trying to find out by conducting this experiment?  That applets are a PITA?